# The Ability to Change Vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The idea of an influx of bad riddles has been raised recently, as well as just an overall feeling of us being different. I am wondering if a change in some voting rules could help with this. When we vote, the vote gets locked after so long. If I don't vote on a question or answer when I first see it, I forget to go back and check it later. So, either I run the risk of up/down voting something that I would vote the other way once I see the solution, or I completely forget.

Can we look into changing the system for us so that we can more easily change our vote (mostly on questions) once an answer is posted to account for questions whose answers change opinions?

Comment: This is something that is different on Puzzling.SE than on other sites.  On most sites, you can tell the quality of a question as soon as it is posted, but here, sometimes it looks good, but has a terrible answer; or looks lame, but you realize after it's answered how good a question it really is.

Comment: Yes, Puzzling.SE is different in that regard. But it doesn't warrant changing the system. It just means you should ***value your vote*** more than you do currently.

Comment: On a related note:  I would really like the ability to see _recently accepted_ answers, i.e. a list of questions in descending order of date of acceptance.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder: You should post that as a separate post.

Comment: Does this answer provide any relevance (my post from a previous question), or better yet, does the question in self apply? http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1671/2383

Comment: While I'd love to see a list of recently ticked questions for other purposes, I think the more important stat in this case is recently modified (*question-only*) lists/filters and/or recently reopened questions.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that this is the intended usage behind the Favourite star. The name of it (Favourite) implies additional meaning, but in reality, it just adds the item to your watch list. This list can be used to easily find marked posts again, and even indicates which ones have been updated since you marked it.

If you feel an unanswered puzzle deserves an upvote (usually because it's interesting or well-written), upvote it.
If you feel an unanswered puzzle deserves a downvote (usually because it is unclear or poorly worded), downvote it.
If you want to wait until an accepted answer is provided to a puzzle before passing judgement, mark it as Favourite and check your Favourites list periodically. You can unfavourite an item at any time.

See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) for more info on Favourites.

Comment: And this post too: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/why-do-people-favorite-a-question-but-not-upvote-it?s=1|0.8977

Comment: I can definitely see this, and I will start doing it more, but for a unique site like PSE, it still seems (to me) like it would be more useful to simply be able to change the vote.

Comment: At the risk of sounding completely moronic, I have never found my "Favorites" list.  Where is it?

Comment: @feelinferrety [**Click me**](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7586/feelinferrety?tab=favorites)